# How to abandon a connection attempt if it takes too long

Tags: blackberry, https, timeout, connection

I have an application I've written that works perfectly in the simulator. When I put it on a device however it does not.

It does one HttpRequest to get and parse all the xml containing all the urls of the thumbnails I want to download. Once all of that is done and the thread is closed, it will create a new thread which loops through all the url's and requests/downloads the thumbnails (7 at a time for each XML request). It works fine for the first 14-28 downloads, then one or two will fail. My question here is, how can I get the code:

```
_connFact.setAttemptsLimit(2);
_connFact.setRetryFactor(500);
_connFact.setTimeLimit(500);
_connFact.setConnectionTimeout(2000);
_connFact.setTimeoutSupported(true);
        //Hangs on the line below for 2-5 minutes on the ones that it failed to download
        //trans[i] is just a list of Transports that I've prechecked for coverage and availability
    for (int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++){
        _httpsConn = (HttpsConnection)_connFact.getConnection(URLFactory.EncodeUrl(trans[i], _url), trans[i], null).getConnection();
        if (_httpsConn != null){
        break;
        }
    }
```

to just die if it fails to connect. I'd rather have the app continue and display a broken thumbnail then hang for the 2+ minutes per failure it does now.

Comment: Never programmed on blackberry but it looks to me like you should create 2 factories. 1 With a long timeout for your first request, long with short one and no retry for your other thumbnail requests.

Comment: this code is only for the thumbnail requests. I call this function 7 times with the _url being each thumbnails location

Comment: @DFTR: +1. Despite `_connFact.setConnectionTimeout(2000);` (2 secs timeout) it still takes up to 2+ mins... I have the same issue you describe (I don't use `ConnectionFactory`, but I use `Connector.open(url)` to get an `HttpConnection`). When I have batch image download (I download images one by one - each image uses its own new connection), then sometimes (approx. one request from ten) it hangs with 2+ timeout. I still don't know why this happens ans how to fix it. This happens even on simulator, the BB transport is 100% permanently available.

Comment: Its like it uses up the devices available connections as well. You can't do anything with whatever your transport is (wifi, 3g etc) until you either wait that 2-5 minutes, OR recycle the radio. I'd be curious to have a new 9850 or something and see if BBOS7 does this.

Comment: @DFTR: You know what.. I have an idea to try - what if you set a 1 or 2 seconds delay (on a non-UI thead, of course) before starting a new download? This is to ensure the OS have enough free time to release all resources it may still hold for the already executed connections.

Comment: I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: based on [this] (http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/How_To_-_Control_the_connection_timeout_for_TCP_connections_through_BlackBerry_Mobile_Data_System_Connection_Service.html?nodeid=1235131&vernum=0) There is no connection timeout that you can set unless you're on a bes?. Thus, how to deal with a failed connection is.... you're screwed?

Comment: @DFTR: Note they are talking about `StreamConnection` (not `HttpConnection`). AFAIK, there is no possibility to set a timeout for `HttpConnection`s. To name this as is - BB API sucks in this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of research:

An HttpConnection as most know is blocking. When doing many HttpRequests one after another the blackberry has trouble handling it. Eventually one will fail. This is a problem because ConnectionTimeout=Value flag is [only supported with MDS / BES connections](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html). Thus the connection does not time out and continues blocking. Unfortunatly this also blocks other applications (including browser etc) from working as well. The default timeout is 1 day, which means, the only way to fix this is to recycle the radio.

Thus the proper way to do many HttpRequests simultaneously is to use a NonBlockingSenderDestination with an application connection factory context like so and implement a separate MessageListener:

```
    _factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        _factory.setAttemptsLimit(3);
        if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
            _factory.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[] { TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI,
                    TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR });
        }

        _context = new Context("yourappname", _factory);

NonBlockingSenderDestination destination = DestinationFactory.createNonBlockingSenderDestination(_context,
                    URI.create(url), this);
            destination.send();
```

This is the proper way to do it because you cannot abandon a conventional HttpConnection unless it is an MDS connection. This then, allows the OS to handle it and the application listens for a response. If no response is forthcoming, then it was abandoned by the OS.

Comment: "The default timeout is 1 day".. Are you sure? Is there any "official" info on this? My experience says it is 2+ mins.

Comment: timeLimit: 1 DAY
attemptsLimit: 1
Sorry. This is what I meant. Its for connection factory